# One thousand year old riddle (from the Exeter Book)

Tags: riddle, explanation

This riddle is from the Exeter Book, circa 960-990 A.D.:

> Clothes make no sound when I tread ground
>   Or dwell in dwellings or disturb the flow.
>   And lofty air and gear at times
>   Above men's towns will lift me:
>   Brisk breezes bear me far and then
>   My frettings loudly rush and ring
>   Above the people and most clearly sing
>   When I forth-fare on air
>   And feel and know
>   No fold, no flow.

(trans. from Old English by Geoffrey Grigson)

In modern form, we would probably end this with the question: "What am I?" although it seems to be lacking from the original text.

I won't spoil it for those that want to try to solve it.  The answer is:

> A swan.

I am posting this here because I want to know *how* that answer makes sense. Even accounting for the poetic flair induced by the Old English origins, I simply do not understand how that answer fits.

Can someone explain the answer please?

Comment: May I ask how you know what the answer is? Was it included in the original book?

Comment: Fair question. When I first came by the riddle, that was the solution presented. This seems to be reiterated on various reprints of the riddle, e.g. https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_Riddles_of_the_Exeter_Book/21 (slightly different translation) or https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/theriddleages.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/notes-on-riddle-7/amp/. The latter provides partial explanation (and even notes who solved it - in 1859).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems easy enough to explain how most of this applies to

> any water-fowl: its fine plumage, unlike some human clothing, doesn't make rustling noises or the like as the swan moves, which it may do on land or on water. Or it may fly high in the air.

But why

> a swan

in particular? (I've looked in a few places and everyone agrees that this specific thing is the intended answer.) I think there are two clues. The first is in this bit:

> My frettings loudly rush and ring
>   Above the people and most clearly sing
>   When I forth-fare on air

I'll quote a couple of other translations/paraphrases. First, from [here](https://anglosaxonpoetry.camden.rutgers.edu/exeter-book-riddles/):

> wide over the people. My bangles then
>   loudly jangle, jingling—brightly singing,
>   when I am not resting upon
>   the flood or the fold—a faring stranger.

And from [here](https://anthonywilsonpoetry.com/2013/09/07/lifesaving-poems-riddle-7-the-exeter-book/):

> My white pinions
>   resound very loudly, ring with a melody,
>   sing out clearly, when I sleep not on
>   the soil or settle on grey waters — a travelling spirit.

And from [here](https://sites.nd.edu/manuscript-studies/2019/12/06/encoded-references-in-exeter-book-riddles/) which I found the most informative and is the source for much of what I say below:

> My adornments then resound loudly, and ring, and sing brightly, when I am not hanging on sea or land, a traveling spirit.

The key point is that the riddle is making a deliberate contrast: the "clothing" of the riddle's subject is quiet *on land and on water* but resounds, sings, rings, jangles, etc., *when it is flying in the air*. And

> it turns out that in mediaeval times it was thought, or at least said, that the swan's *feathers* produce a beautiful musical song while it is in flight. (A flying swan's wings absolutely *do* make a sound, but I don't think it's particularly beautiful or musical.) The last of the pages I linked to above cites an Old English poem called *Phoenix*, which compares the phoenix's beautiful song favourably with, among other things, "[the feathers of the swan](https://anglosaxonpoetry.camden.rutgers.edu/the-phoenix/)", and a letter from Gregory of Nazianzus that I wasn't been able to find but Quuxplusone kindly located in a book (see comments) that has a swan speaking of "when we allow our wings to blow something sweet and harmonious to the western wind".

The second thing that might be relevant is in the second line of the section I quoted above. Here it is in the original Old English:

> ofer folc byreð. | Frætwe mine
>   swogað hlude | ond swinsiað,
>   torhte singað, | þonne ic getenge ne beom

Those words "swogað" and "swinsiað"

> are etymologically related to *swan*! The swan appears to get its name for its reputation for beautiful singing, and the OED entry for "swan" makes specific reference to that verb "swinsian", meaning to make melody.

I am no Anglo-Saxon scholar, and maybe more is known than this, but I think the above is sufficient to explain why the specific answer everyone gives is surely the intended one.

Comment: Nice explanation! I’ll keep the question open for a few days to see if any scholars can improve on this.

Comment: This Q&A would fit equally well on [literature.se], even.

Comment: It looks like the Gregory-to-Celeusius letter about swans is [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=vUW0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA148): _Gregory of Nazianzus's Letter Collection_, translated by Bradley K. Storin (2019). University of California Press: Oakland. [ISBN 9780520304123](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9780520304123). Epistle 114, page 148.

Comment: Nice! I'll put a little quotation into the answer.

Comment: There is nothing "imaginary" about the sound of a swan's wings when it is flying. Listen to this video clip. https://youtu.be/ZsuvYLLSjAU?t=8 Many other water birds' wings also "sing" when they are flying. Many swan species (but not mute swans) also make noisy vocal calls when flying.

Comment: Oh, for sure they make a sound. But I wouldn't call it musical or song-like, myself. I'll edit my answer so it doesn't look as if I'm saying they're silent in flight.

Comment: So part of the reasoning is a pair of puns that only work in the original old-English?  That would certainly help to explain OP's confusion!

Comment: They certainly work _better_ in Old English. I'm not sure they're exactly puns; there really is an etymological relationship there.